# jquery-select2 selected value partially visible

Tags: jquery-select2

For some reason in some cases select2 (version 4.0.3) shows partially selected value.

HTML:

```
Selected value partially visible<select name="example" id="wraps">
<option value="71.0">Harju maakond</option>
<option value="73.0">Hiiumaa</option>
<option value="48.0">Ida-Virumaa</option>
</select>
<br>
Selected value fully visible
<select name="example2">
<option value="71.0">Harju maakond</option>
<option value="73.0">Hiiumaa</option>
<option value="48.0">Ida-Virumaa</option>

</select>
```

JS:

```
$('#wraps').select2({width: 'resolve', dropdownAutoWidth : true});
```

Result:

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9cJi.png)

fiddle also
https://jsfiddle.net/nhqzzf64/2/

When using default drop-down I see value "Harju maakond" but with select2 I see "Harju ma..."

Setting exact width for dropdown is not an option because I don't know the maximum width. Content is changing.

width: 'auto' option is also not suitable because I want fix width after page is rendered.

Any solution how to set the width the same as original drop-down?

Answer (score 0):

You can try expanding the `select2` box with pure CSS (note the `!important` rule):

```
.select2-container {
  width: 200px !important;
}
```

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nhqzzf64/3/).

Comment: Problem is that I don't know what will be the width because the content is changing in drop-down.

Answer (score 0):

the "resolve" option does not appear to be supported in 4.0.3

Your best bet is to use width: 100% when initializing select2, and place the element within a container you control the width of.

```
$('#wraps').select2( { 
    width: '100%'
});
```

```js
$('#wraps').select2({width: '100%'});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

Selected value fully visible
<select name="example" id="wraps">
<option value="71.0">Harju maakond</option>
<option value="73.0">Hiiumaa</option>
<option value="48.0">Ida-Virumaa</option>
</select>

<p></p>
Selected value fully visible
<select name="example2">
<option value="71.0">Harju maakond</option>
<option value="73.0">Hiiumaa</option>
<option value="48.0">Ida-Virumaa</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve to problem when getting the original width() and specifying also font-size via css and after that converting drop-down with select2().